# .VALIDATE : CANCEL THE VALIDATION FOR A FIELD BASED ON REMOTE RESPONSE

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

Consider the following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#register_employee_form").validate({
    errorElement: "p",      
    rules: 
    {
        forename: "required",
        surname: "required",
        reportingto: 
        {
            required : true,
            remote: {
                url: "ajax/error_checking/check_reporting_to.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    reportingto: function() {
                        return $( "#reportingto" ).val();   // pass reportingto field
                    }
                },
                complete: function(response) {
                    if (response.responseText == "false")
                    {
                        // CANCEL THE VALIDATION FOR THIS FIELD
                        // HOW DO I DO IT??????
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        forename: "Please enter your first name",
        surname: "Please enter your last name",
        reportingto: "Employee required"

    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
});
```

I want to be able to cancel the validation for the field "reportingto" if the response back from the AJAX call is false.

Any ideas/help gratefully received..!

Regards

Oli

THANKS FOR THE RESPONSES SO FAR BUT I STILL HAVE ISSUES.

I tried using depends but still doesn't work as required:

Take the following "cut down" test code

```
        test_field: 
        {
            required: {
                remote: {

                  param: {

                    url: "ajax/error_checking/check_reporting_to.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        reporting_to: function() {
                            return $( "#test_field_to" ).val();   // pass reporting_to field
                        }
                    },
                    complete: function(response) {
                        if (response.responseText == "false")
                        {
                            cancel_flag = 1;
                        }
                    }

                  } // param
                  ,
                 depends: function() {
                     if(cancel_flag == 1)
                     {
                         return false;
                     }
                     else 
                     {
                         return true;
                     }
                  }

                } // remote
            } // required
        },
```

and the field

```
 <td class="column_1"><label>TEST FIELD</label></td>                    
 <td><input name="test_field" id="test_field" value=""  /></td>
```

If I force a "false" return from the AJAX it still triggers a validation error message for the field.

Comment: Use depends , http://blog.adrianlawley.com/jquery-validation-rules-depends/

Comment: `rules: {
address: {
required: {
depends: function(element) {
if ($('#newsletterByPost').is(':checked')){
return true;
}else{
return false;
}
}
}
}
}`

Comment: Can u consult senior PHP/javasript developer in ur company about this ?

Comment: Just me I'm afraid. I work alone. Been away a couple of weeks. Will take another look at it. It ought to work so I cannot understand why it doesn't. I will try a new example stripping everything right back to ensure nothing else is affecting it.

Answer (score 0):

Use depends Parameter.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
var cancelFlag=0; //Dont cancel validation

$("#register_employee_form").validate({
    errorElement: "p",      
    rules: 
    {
        forename:{required : true},//Do u assure on this LINE CODE BY U WORK ? I made it Proper , If ur Old code works then no problem
        surname:{required : true},//Do u assure on this LINE CODE BY U WORK ? I made it Proper , If ur Old code works then no problem
        reportingto: 
        {                       
            required : true,
            remote: {

              param: {

                url: "ajax/error_checking/check_reporting_to.php",
                type: "post",
                data: {
                    reportingto: function() {
                        return $( "#reportingto" ).val();   // pass reportingto field
                    }
                },
                complete: function(response) {
                    if (response.responseText == "false")
                    {
                        cancelFlag = 1;
                        // CANCEL THE VALIDATION FOR THIS FIELD
                        // HOW DO I DO IT??????
                    }
                }

              }//Param
              ,
             depends: function() {
                 if(cancelFlag==1)
                 {
                     return false;
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                     return true;
                 }
              }

            }//Remote


        }
    },
    messages: {
        forename: "Please enter your first name",
        surname: "Please enter your last name",
        reportingto: "Employee required"

    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});

});
```

The workaround I found is to nest the standard remote: properties under a property named param:. If the depends: function returns true, it will reference the properties as you would expect.

For documentation see [**HERE**](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/431)

The above Code should work , U have alternative also ..

```
    reportingto: 
    {                       
        required : {
            remote: {

          param: {

            url: "ajax/error_checking/check_reporting_to.php",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                reportingto: function() {
                    return $( "#reportingto" ).val();   // pass reportingto field
                }
            },
            complete: function(response) {
                if (response.responseText == "false")
                {
                    cancelFlag = 1;
                    // CANCEL THE VALIDATION FOR THIS FIELD
                    // HOW DO I DO IT??????
                }
            }

          }//Param
          ,
         depends: function() {
             if(cancelFlag==1)
             {
                 return false;
             }
             else 
             {
                 return true;
             }
          } 

        }//Remote
        }
    }
```

FOR reporting element.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers and they have help a little but I still cannot get this to work how I want it. SEE ADDITIONS TO QUESTION

Comment: That solution above doesn't seem to trigger the AJAX call for some reason. Still struggling with this.

Comment: @OliverTsang , have you struggling with this problem from last month ?